# how add more icons in toolbar in MaterialViewPager android lib

Tags: java, android, android-layout

hi there I try wrok with [MaterialViewPager](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager)

I could install it (sample version). But I couldn't underestand it about actionbar and toolbar

I have 2 relative problem with it:

1- this template has a right sliding that works only with touching right (not with icon like this picture)

[image]

Also I want add some toolbar icons.

But I do not know how can I add icons!

please see mainactivity.java code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setTitle("");

        mViewPager = (MaterialViewPager) findViewById(R.id.materialViewPager);

        toolbar = mViewPager.getToolbar();
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
                actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
                actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
                actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            }
        }
```

if I change `if (toolbar != null)` to if (toolbar == null) the sliding icon will hide and just a right arrow appear like this picture:

[image]

I know it is not a magic but I checked all java code and menu_main and all files in style folder. I do not know how this array apear here? becuase there is not any toolbar or actionbar in the project. and how can I add more icon?

SO This is my problem:
1- how can I active icon sliding?
2- where is source of 'right arrow' and how can I add more icons?

[image]

and how can I keep both icons in '1' and '2' !

Answer (score 0):

That icon comes from Google support library and it is placed and managed according to Material design.

Changing or doing anything with it violates Material Design Principles.

It should be default.